# Why can't I select text when pointer-events:none and position:absolute are applied?

Tags: css, css-position, pointer-events

I can't select text when the parent `.block` element has `pointer-events:none` and the child element has `position:absolute`. When I remove `position:absolute`, it works, but I need this positioning.

```css
.block{
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  pointer-events:none;
}

p{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="block">hovered</div>
<div class="block"><p>can`t be hovered</p></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `pointer-events: initial;` to your selector: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/747fu45c/1/). Note: `pointer-events: all;` appears to work as well, but the docs mention it's an SVG only value, so I'd stick with initial to restore the pointer events to their initial state.

For reference, `pointer-events` has quite a few options, which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).